# Issue with 9 patch generator

Tags: android

I am trying to generate 9 patch images using 
http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/nine-patches.html

The source image has transparent background , but the images generated by the tool are having unexpected borders . I am not getting why is this happening . Please help me.

[image]

Comment: Post that generated image.

Comment: Hi Paresh Mayani ... i have added one of the generated images.

Comment: It's totally normal the black lines are defining the "patch" areas!

Comment: Seems to be normal, the black "border" you see indicate the stretchable region (top and left) and the content region (bottom and right)

Comment: use this image that will not shows border in your app..

Comment: Thank you all.. actually knew very little about nine patch images .

Comment: That's... just... to... funny :-D

Comment: Ya it might have got funny... I am ashamed , sorry

Answer (score 2):

> The source image has transparent background , but the images generated
>   by the tool are having unexpected borders.

=> First give me answer for this: "Do you really know what is 9-patch image and what is the purpose of creating image using 9-patch tool?"

If you really don't know then read and learn [9-patch tool](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html).

Still FYI, **those lines define the stretchable patches and (optional) content area.** and lines will not get displayed when you run and test app in device or emulator.

Comment: Thank you very much. I should have studied a little more.